# React Navigation poptotop and move to next screen in one animation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

So currently I have a form which is 4 screens long, at the last screen I want to pop to the top of my stack and then navigate to next page with one animation that looks like it's going "backwards"

So using a StackAction.reset won't work, because if i do that, then all my useEffects are called again because it's basically like reinitializing all my controllers.

What i'm currently doing but I don't really like is the following

```
props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Album', params: { id: albumForm.AlbumId.value } }) );
```

This pops me back to my "TabNavigator" and then navigates forward which causes two animations to happen.

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
        index: 1,
        actions: [ 
           NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'TabNavigator' }),
           NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Album', params: { id: albumForm.AlbumId.value } }) 
        ],
});
props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

this was my previous solution but as i mentioned the problem with this is 1. No animation. 2. It reinitializes my controllers, causing my useEffects to refire.

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: I believe the only way to achieve the so-called `going backwards` effect is either:calling `goBack` or have the page you are trying to go be part of the route history and `navigate` to there directly

Comment: it can even look like it's going forward, i just want to not deallocate my tabnavigator route only to reallocate it and have all my useEffects get called again. That's my main concern